# Generic Named Multiple Counter in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, semigroup

I have multiple case classes that represent some sort of dimensions, and some sort of field level statistics that can be aggregated agnostic from all the other fields. This forms a semigroup by defining `combine`

```scala
case class Precipitation(date: String, rainInches: Double, snowInches: Double)

def combine(p1: Precipitation, p2:Precipitation): Precipitation = {
   p1.copy(rainInches=p1.rainInches + p2.rainInches,
           snowInches=p1.snowInches + p2.snowInches)
}

case class GroceryList(
  groceryListId: String, 
  groceryStoreName: String, 
  eggs: Int, 
  peaches: Int, 
  flourPounds: Double)


def combine(g1: GroceryList, g2: GroceryList): GroceryList = {
   g1.copy(eggs = g1.eggs + g2.eggs,
           peaches = g1.peaches + g2.peaches, 
           flourPounds = g1.flourPounds + g2.flourPounds)
}
```

For a pure aggregation with no state like this, it would be nice to define a more generic semigroup trait that both `Precipitation` and `GroceryList` extend, that can deal with arbitrary names and numbers of fields.

Comment: [**Kittens**](https://github.com/typelevel/kittens) allows you to derive such `Semigroup` for `case classes`

Comment: In Scala such things are solved with type classes and type class derivation.